# unable to concatenate variable with sql query

Tags: java, mysql, concatenation, intellij-14

Here is sample code ...

```
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String query = "select * from work_product where product_name ='" + ch + "' ";
System.out.println(query); // displaying only `
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    System.out.println(query);
    while (rs.next()){
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2));
    }
```

If String passed Instead of passing variable then it works ...like

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from work_product where product_name ='product' ");
```

I also used preparedStatement...but not working ...

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from work_thing_db.work_product where product_name = ? ");
statement.setString(1,ch);
```

Here is full code ....

```
@FXML protected void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt)throws Exception {
        //SetTimer();

        if (evt.getCode() != KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
            String ch = evt.getText();
            //runThread();
            concateString = concateString + ch; //concateString has scope
            if (evt.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                System.out.println("Enter Key Fired ");
                System.out.println(concateString);
                dbSearch(concateString);
            }
        }
}
private void dbSearch(String ch){
        System.out.println("In dbSearch");
        System.out.println("Concate String :"+ch);
        String query = "select * from work_product where product_name ='" + ch + "' ";
        System.out.println("Query is :"+query);
        dbConnector conn = new dbConnector();
        Connection con = conn.dbConnection();
        try {

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2));
            }
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    }
```

Using : IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE
**Output :**
Enter key Fired
    product
    In dbSearch
    Concat String :product
    '

kindly point out my mistake ... i'm new in java... and further i need to use `like` and `or` with it .... please provide answer with explanation... Thanks in advance.

Comment: define `not working`?

Comment: not fetching any data from db ... there is no error

Comment: dude just check the value of `ch` or try to print query in SOP and compare with your actual query

Comment: already checked it..

Comment: Strange, because there is no such discrimination I have ever seen even if query is a constant string or constructed dynamically.

Comment: me too ... i have already used such query...

Comment: post the query printed by the variable and also do you have try catch?

Comment: yes i have a try catch... let me update my full code

Comment: now it is edited ... Kindly check it

Comment: you dont get output for `System.out.println("Query is :"+query);` ?

Comment: i got only single quote( ' )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't thought of it....

```
private void dbSearch(String ch){
        System.out.println("In dbSearch");
        System.out.println("Concate String :"+ch);
        ch = ch.trim().toString(); // trim and type cast ... its working
        String query = "select * from work_product where product_name ='" + ch + "' ";
        System.out.println("Query is :"+query);
        dbConnector conn = new dbConnector();
        Connection con = conn.dbConnection();
        try {

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2));
            }
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    }
```

Now it is fetching data properly ...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible there is no match in the data. You could run a non filtered query first and see what values you have for product_name in the table.

Comment: that data is exist in db ... If String passed Instead of passing variable then it works

Comment: Asking the obvious here but is your variable holding the value you are expecting? Check for extra white spaces and different capitalization. You should log the exact query statement your code builds with that variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in the way you concatenate the string

```
    if (evt.getCode() != KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
        String ch = evt.getText();
        //runThread();
        concateString = concateString + ch; //concateString has scope
        if (evt.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            System.out.println("Enter Key Fired ");
            System.out.println(concateString);
            dbSearch(concateString);
        }
    }
```

so when the user will enter "ENTER" (can be \n or \r) you will concatenate before the condition of the key value so `concateString` will always contain your string + "ENTER" (i.e. the carriage return). Thats the reason you only get the quote when you print your query

Not to modify much of your code, you can do

```
    if (evt.getCode() != KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
        String ch = evt.getText();
        //runThread();
        if (evt.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            System.out.println("Enter Key Fired ");
            System.out.println(concateString);
            dbSearch(concateString);
        } else {
            concateString = concateString + ch; //concateString has scope
        }
    }
```

and so you will pass the correct string